# C++ Formatting Output Issue

Tags: c++

I have tried setw() function from iomanip library, wonder how this one text line can't be aligned.
Here's the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    ifstream productlist;
    productlist.open("product.txt");
    if (!productlist.is_open()) {
        cout << "File failed to open \n";
        return 0;
    }
    string name, squantity, sprice;
    int quantity, price;
    string line;

    cout << "Product Name\t"  <<  "Quantity\t" << "Price\t"  << "Value\n";
    while (getline(productlist, line)) {
        stringstream ss(line);
        getline(ss, name, '/');
        getline(ss, squantity, '/');
        quantity = stoi(squantity);
        getline(ss, sprice);
        price = stoi(sprice); 
        int value = quantity * price;
        cout << name << "\t\t"<< quantity << "\t\t" <<  price << "\t" << value << endl;
    }
    productlist.close();
}
```

and here's the text file that I used in the said code.

```
Apple/5/10
Water/1/40
Pencil/10/11
Orange/2/10
Lemon/1/12
Krunch/2/50
Coco/2/14
Burgers/2/25
Lemonades/2/21
Pizzas/2/250
```

and here is the output

```
Product Name    Quantity        Price   Value
Apple           5               10      50
Water           1               40      40
Pencil          10              11      110
Orange          2               10      20
Lemon           1               12      12
Krunch          2               50      100
Coco            2               14      28
Burgers         2               25      50
Lemonades               2               21      42
Pizzas          2               250     500
```

I can use the setw() function and it would end up still the same as the output that I shown here.

Comment: "'\t'" always advances to the next tab stop ***after*** the current position. Even if you already printed a text string that's large enough to have gone past the next tab stop. So, "\t\t" gets you to the third tab stop, since you're already past tab stop #1. Remember the Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: your computer will always to exactly what you tell it to do, instead of what you want it to do.

Comment: Insert just one tab if the product name is more than 8 characters. Ugly fix, but you gotta do what you gotta do

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using tabs to space things out, use `setw` and related methods:

```
 cout << left << setw(20) << setfill(' ') << name << left << setw(20) << quantity << ...
```

See [here](https://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/text-alignment-in-Cplusplus.htm) for more examples.